# how to get parent view tag and child tag at a time while clicking child?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have dynamically created view ,inside that dynamically created buttons.while clicking the buttons I have to get both view's and button's tag.
I have used the code as

```
-(void)addButton
{
    for (int j=0; j<[defaultNumberAry count]; j++) {

    numberButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(n, 0, 40, 40)];
    n=n+42;
    [numberButton setBackgroundImage:[defaultNumberAry objectAtIndex:j] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    numberButton.tag=j;
    [numberTagAry addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j]];
    numberButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [numberButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    numberButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [numberView addSubview:numberButton];

}
}
-(void)addView:(int)yv
{
n=22;
numberView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, yv, 400, 44)];
numberView.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
numberView.tag=b;
b++;
numberView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touched:)];
[tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[numberView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

}
-(void)pressed:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    if(!button.selected){
        NSLog(@"selected btn tag:%d",button.tag);       
                       }
}
- (void) touched:(id)sender
{
    int v=((UIGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag;
    NSLog(@"view tag:::%d",v);

  }
```

some times the control goes to button press and some times to view touched.I have to get both tag at a time.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add a subview like so:

```
[numberView addSubview:numberButton];
```

`numberButton` becomes a **subview** of `numberView`; also `numberView` becomes the **superview** of `numberButton`. And you can access it through that property.

```
-(void)pressed:(id)sender{
    UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    UIView *superViewOfPressedButton = pressedButton.superview;
    NSLog(@"Tag of button:%i Tag of pressed button's button view is %i",pressedButton.tag,superViewOfPressedButton.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'll only capture the users touch in one place, not two like you're trying to do.  You can drop the GestureRecognizer altogether here and just use the touch event for the button.

Then you have a few options to accomplish the next bit you want.  In the button's touch handler, 'pressed' in your case above, you can get sender.tag which would be the button, and sender.superview.tag which would be the view.

Alternately, you could use a formula and just use the one tag.  For example, (view.tag * 1000) + (button.tag).  So that would mean the first button on the first view would have a tag of 1001.  The 1000 represents the view, and the 1 represents the button.  The eighth button on the fifth view would be 5008.  You just need to do some simple math to extract the original numbers.